# How prevent update some fields in updateOrCreate?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I try to check if Instagram profile exists in my database if not exists I create it, if exists I update all fields.

```
 InstagramProfile::updateOrCreate([
       'instagram_id' => $instagramUser->data->id,
    ], [
       'profile_id' => $author_id = Profile::firstOrCreate([
          'username' => $instagramUser->data->username,
       ])->id,
       ...
    ]);
```

Problem: when it new `InstagramProfile` - all works ok, but when I update exists I create new `Profile`. 
Question: how prevent update some fields in `updateOrCreate()`?

Comment: do u have a unique column name in your table?

Comment: @SalarBahador only id

Comment: Have you tried to get `$profile_id` beforehand and then just pass that variable/value instead of getting/creating inside `updateOrCreate()` method?

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to set the attributes you don't want filled on update as guarded.

Comment: And I can't mass assign this attribute in create